# When should I inherit ValidationAttribute or choose Remote Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to check in a formular wether a new entered certain user name exists.

The user name is the unique identifier of a user.

The user name should have at least 2 chars minimum.

Now I thought of using the Remote Validation + StringLength Validation Attribute.

But I could also inherit from ValidationAttribute and make my service.UserExists call there + string length stuff.

What should I favor?

Comment: The method your `[Remote]` attribute calls can check for uniqueness and string length (and return an appropriated error message), but a `[Remote]` attribute gives client side validation only, so you should have the `[StringLength]` attribute anyway, and you also be checking uniqueness on the server again when you post. Not sure why you would want to create you own attribute.

Comment: "...Remote attribute gives client side validation only..." Are you sure? actually its server side validation...

Comment: `[Remote]` provide client side validation only. It uses ajax (client side code) to call a server method and returns json to the client. Unlike say `[Required]` or `[StringLength]` which is validated on the server by the `DefaultModelBinder` (errors are added to `ModelState`), there is no server side validation for `[Remote]` when the model is bound during a POST. Therefore you should still perform the same check in you POST method.

Comment: ok thanks then the 'remote' confused me. It suggest that the validation is done remotely somewhere far away like on the server. But you are correct => // client side remote validation is not honored by server side validation (modelstate) , thus I have to do a check again when the data is POSTed.